# Open Dynamics Engine não reconhece colisão entre cilindros

Tags: c++

Estou utilizando a biblioteca [ODE (Open Dynamics Engine)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Dynamics_Engine) para a simular física na minha aplicação. Para criar o bounding box e geometria do cilindro estou usando o seguinte código

```
dMass m1;
dMassSetZero(&m1);
dMassSetCappedCylinderTotal(&m1, mass, 2, lx/2.0, lz);
dBodySetMass(body, &m1);
dBodySetPosition(body, x0, y0, z0);
dBodySetRotation(body, R);

dGeomID geom = dCreateCylinder(PhysicsEngine::space, lx / 2.0, lz);
dGeomSetBody(geom, body);
```

Nenhum erro é gerado, e objeto é gerado corretamente. Porém ao executar o tratamento de colisões:

```
const int N = 100;
dContact contact[N];
int n = dCollide(o1, o2, N, &contact[0].geom, sizeof(dContact));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    contact[i].surface.mode = dContactSlip2 | dContactSlip1;
    contact[i].surface.mu = dInfinity;
    contact[i].surface.slip1 = 0.1;
    contact[i].surface.slip2 = 0.1;
    dJointID c = dJointCreateContact(PhysicsEngine::world, PhysicsEngine::contactgroup, &contact[i]);
    dJointAttach(c, dGeomGetBody(contact[i].geom.g1), dGeomGetBody(contact[i].geom.g2));
}
```

A engine reconhece colisões de:

- Plano e Cilindro
- Cubo e Cilindro
- Esfera e Cilindro

mas não reconhece Cilindro com Cilindro, como na imagem

[image: ODE não reconhecendo colisões entre cilindros]

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que pode ser? Estou utilizando a versão atual da biblioteca, disponível neste [repositório](https://bitbucket.org/odedevs/ode) e usei o seguinte comando para compila-lo

```
./premake4.exe --with-tests --with-libccd --with-demos vs2010
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação wiki da própria biblioteca, na seção [Collision Tests Supported](https://www.ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:_Collision_Detection#Collision_tests_supported). Lá tem uma nota (nota 3) dizendo que as colisões entre cilindros requerem que a [libccd esteja habilitada](https://www.ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Enabling_the_libccd_colliders). Talvez seja isso que falte.

Comment: Só agora eu notei que na sua linha de comando você de fato já inclui a tal libccd. Bom, fora isso, talvez você esteja pegando as DLLs de um local equivocado? Outra coisa: o seu "tratamento" de colisões na verdade cria joints. O problema é na criação dos joints ou de fato a chamada de `dCollide` não tá funcionando? Depure pra ter certeza.

Comment: @LuizVieira Valeu, funcionou direitinho. Eu tinha recompilado, mas só atualizei o cabeçalhos (.h) e as bibliotecas (.lib), mas não atualizei o DLL. Como não apresentava erros pensei que estava tudo em ordem

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xyjOWwT

Comment: O tratamento de colisão ocorre em loop,  e recupera todas as colisões com o dCollide, em seguida eu configuro as forças através do dCreateContact

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda dos comentários. Para resolver este problema eu precisei recompilar a biblioteca do [ODE (Open Dynamics Engine)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Dynamics_Engine) junto com a aplicação [libccd](https://github.com/danfis/libccd) (Biblioteca para colisões entre objetos convexos). Acontece que o ODE, como depende atualmente de contribuições, não possui uma implementação nativa de colisão para cilindro para cilindro (por se tratar de um objeto convexo). Porém a biblioteca **libccd** pode ser compilado junto com o **ODE** para complementar a engine, além disso o **libccd** é utilizado por outras bibliotecas de simulação de físicas que você pode encontrar neste [artigo](https://github.com/danfis/libccd).

Aproveito para criar um tutorial em Português para esta engine de simulação fisica. Eu vou explicar passo a passo como fazer isso para **Microsoft Visual Studio (2017)**.

**1.** Primeiro você precisa ir no [repositório do bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/odedevs/ode/downloads/) do ODE e baixar o código-fonte (compactado em tar.gz) e extrair em alguma pasta.

**2.** Abra o *prompt de comando* e vá para a pasta build (cd ./pasta/do/ode/build)

**3.** Execute o comando para gerar o projeto para Visual Stuido, ativando a opção do libccd

```
./premake4.exe --with-tests --with-libccd --with-demos vs2010
```

(Observação, atualmente o ODE possui configuração para vs2010 para baixo, porém funciona no Visual Studio 2017)

**4.** O comando irá gerar o projeto para visual studio na pasta **./build/vs2010** e abra **ode.sln**

**5.** Dentro do Visual Studio compile todos os projetos (talvez seja necessário redirecionar o projeto para o SDK da sua IDE).

**6.** Na pasta principal vá para a :

- **\include**, para adicionar as duas pastas com arquivos de cabeçalho ao seu projeto através das configurações do Visual Studio, em **Diretórios VC++ > Diretório de Inclusão**
- **\lib\DebugDoubleDLL**, para adicionar os arquivos (menos os de teste), ao seu projeto através das configurações do Visual Studio, em **Diretórios VC++ > Diretório de Biblioteca**

**7.** Copie o arquivo **ode_doubled.dll** na pasta de saída do executável (para evitar erros), arquivo que esta na pasta **\lib\DebugDoubleDLL**.

**8.** No seu projeto, vá em **Configurações do Projeto > C/C++ > Pré-processador > Definições de Pré-Processador** e adicione o pré-processador **dDOUBLE**

**9.** No seu projeto, vá em **Configurações do Projeto > Vinculador > Entrada > Dependências Adicionais** e adicione a dependência **ode_doubled.lib**

**10.** Já está configurado o ODE, para testar use este exemplo do [tutorial de demura](http://demura.net/english/ode3) e meu código na pergunta para criar um cilindro.

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]